# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate failed when trying to update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to update an Object, with new array data. I receive the message:

> "MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at
> path "playlistContent" "

And I receive "undefined".

When I console.log my array data, everything is fine, but I am not able to update my document, and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
router.post("/addspot/:id", async (req, res) => {
  
  // Constants 
  let specficPlaylist = await Playlist.findById(req.params.id);
  let spotFrequency = req.body.spotFrequency;
  let spotAllocate = req.body.spotAllocate;
  let populatedPlaylists = [];
  await specficPlaylist.populate("playlistContent").execPopulate();
  
  // For loop for passing in data in the right order
  for (let i = 0; i < specficPlaylist.playlistContent.length; i++) {
    if (i % spotFrequency == 0) {
      populatedPlaylists =
        populatedPlaylists + spotAllocate + ",";
    }
    populatedPlaylists =
      populatedPlaylists +
      specficPlaylist.playlistContent[i]._id+ ",";
  }
  
  // Array of data which I want to update my Object with
  const playlistData = populatedPlaylists.split(",");
  
  // Trying to update my specific document with the above data, but it fails

  await Playlist.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: specficPlaylist._id},
    { playlistContent: playlistData },
    { new: true},
    (err, docs) => {
    }
  );
   res.redirect('back');
});
```

Can anybody help me out, how to pass the data the correct way, and then update my Playlist Object?

// My Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const playlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  playlistName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  playlistDescription: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  playlistUrl: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  playlistContent: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Media" }],


  playlistCreator: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
});

mongoose.model("Playlist", playlistSchema);
```

Comment: Can you post your schema ?

Comment: Of cause! :-) There you go!

Comment: `req.params.id` is a string, you have to convert them first to a valid object id: `mongodb.ObjectID(req.params.id)` (Not sure if "ObjectID" or "ObjectId")

Comment: Thank you Marc!! This is working now! :-)